# labels should not zoom in Qgraphicsitem

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have 300k labels,I want to add them at different zoom levels in QGraphicsItem paint event.

```
void WorldLabels::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setBrush(Qt::red);
    for(int i=0 ;i<no.of labels ; i++)
    {
        painter->drawtext(position,label name);
    }
}
```

the problem is, when I zoom the item,the labels also get zoomed.

I don’t want that, I want to keep my label size as they are initially.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with different zoom levels? Could you please clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Separate your labels in child `QGraphicsTextItem` objects, and use the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag to keep them in the same position but ignoring view/inherited transformations.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but instead of labels I want a marker that stays the same size at all zoom levels. Ie, you zoom into the QGraphicsScene as a map and the marker for the cities stays the same size.  I tried ItemIgnoresTransformations but they acted really weird. All the markers seemed to expand out as a zoomed out and cluster together as I zoomed in.